# How to disable update on sql on a specific field of Yii2 ActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

I would like to grey out a field in ActiveForm. I am quite unsure if this code disables the update on sql already. Is this enough on my _form.php?

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'object_name')->textInput(['readonly' => 'readOnly', 'except' => 'update']) ?>
```

Or should I also modify my model and searchModel classes too?

Comment: you are restricting the input field from input so , it will not update.But it is only for end user. try to use label  instead of input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling the field with read only property .

Here is the syntax which you can use like.......

```
$form->field($model,'field')->textInput(['disabled'=>'disabled','readonly' => 'readOnly']);
```